# Problem with Assets in Grid "Undefined index: grid_row_id; Filename: assets/ft.assets.php; Line Number: 1310"

Tags: assets, php-errors, grid, bug

EE 2.7.1 and Assets 2.2.1

I have a Grid fieldtype (`static-images`) with an Assets column named `image` and a few native text field & dropdown columns. When I have at least one row in the Grid, I get the following error in the frontend:

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: grid_row_id
>
> Filename: assets/ft.assets.php
>
> Line Number: 1310

(I also get the usual "Cannot modify header information" PHP Warnings after that.)

I've reduced the template code that displays the Grid field to the following, which still triggers the PHP Notice:

```
{static-images}
    {static-images:image:url}
{/static-images}
```

Any ideas?

Free Bonus Bug! If I mark the Assets Grid column as "Required" but don't add a file, the in-column error message shows "The %s field is required." :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets 2.2 requires EE 2.7.2 to work with Grid - that was mentioned in the yesterday's blog post about the release :)